# javascript-problem with lightbox 2 on ie7

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

I am having a problem with lightbox2 on IE7. I've modified lightbox, moved the navigation around a bit - everything works fine on Firefox but in IE7 there is a problem: the first time I click on a thumbnail only a part of the background dims and the large image doesn't show. If i try again it works, the problem only occurs after a full pageload.

After pageload:
 
http://www.screencast.com/users/timkl/folders/Jing/media/b33c7728-2247-4b8e-8d65-0eca533e9113

How it should look: 
 
http://www.screencast.com/users/timkl/folders/Jing/media/c65b43d3-6dd8-4524-9afd-ee94d3a5d426

This is the url to the gallery: 
 
http://friedrichjoost.de/temp/index.php?s=art_gallery_sub1

I'm an absolute javascript n00b and have no idea on how to go about this problem, if anybody can give me a hint to what could be wrong it would be highly appreciated.

Also any tips on how to debug javascript on IE is very welcome, I use Firebug for FF but I can't seems to find anything that works as well on IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your DOCTYPE the same as the one on screencast

You have

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

try

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```